# How to set rails root route to README.md?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like to set rails route like github.com

> Since "README.md" file is in the root directory.

Normally we set root as in this format:

```
root :to => controller#method
```

I have no idea what to do with README.md.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just setup a normal route and controller and use a markdown processor to convert the readme contents into HTML.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'commonmarker'
```

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'pages#home'
```

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @readme = CommonMarker.render_html(
      File.read(Rails.root.join('README.md')),
      :DEFAULT
    ).html_safe
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<%= @readme %>
```

This uses [CommonMarker](https://github.com/gjtorikian/commonmarker) which is used by Github. There are plenty of other options though. You may want to invest some time into [caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) so that you don't have to do markdown conversion on every request:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @readme = parse_readme
  end

  private
  def parse_readme
    readme_file = Rails.root.join('README.md')
    cache_key = `git hash-object #{readme_file}`.chomp
    Rails.cache.fetch("README-#{cache_key}") do
      CommonMarker.render_html(
         File.read(readme_file),
         :DEFAULT
       )
    end.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, I glad to ask this question. Thanks @max